# toggle whether or not a jquery DataTables column is sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have seen lots of info on how to initialize a `DataTable` with certain columns that are sortable or not-sortable. However, I can't figure out to disable/enable sorting on a column *after* the table has been initialized. I found a very hacky way to do it, but is there a proper way to do it with the API?

My hack is to target the th, copy the click event, unbind it, then rebind it, like this

```
var _click=$._data($('#myTH')[0],"events").click[0];
$('#myTH').unbind("click");
//do some stuff
//reattach
$('#myTH').bind("click",_click);
```

A simple unbind works great for just turning it off and leaving it off, but I need to be able to toggle it several times. I don't like my solution because

1. `$._data` is a `jQuery` internal and should not be relied upon and
2. it seems like there should be a simple way to do this using the standard `DataTables` API

I am using version 1.10

Comment: Why not use a simple toggle variable in the handling function? or on the click return a toggled boolean?

Comment: because I didn't write the handling function! Its part of the DataTables plugin and I'd rather not mess with it.

Comment: Does it throw an error if you try to bind the same function when it is already bound?

Comment: no, that would just double-bind it, which I don't want. but I don't see how that is relavent here; I'm not trying to change the click event, I just want to temporarily disable it.

Comment: The idea was to basically use a try/catch to toggle the event binding.  This could also be done with a class, if has class unbind and remove class, else bind and add class.  However looking over their API for a few seconds I think you could find an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are defined by a JSON object you can set bSortable to true or false. I've only dynamically made the change on the server but I don't think there's anything to prevent you from doing it on the client and reDrawing the table.

The columns as JSON would look like

```
var columns = [{"bSortable":false,"sWidth":"80px","sTitle":"Fancy Column 1 Title","mData":"Id"},{"bSortable":false,"sWidth":"80px","sTitle":"Fancy Column 2 Title","mData":"name"}]

table = $j('#datatable').dataTable({
                    'sPaginationType': 'custom',
                    'aoColumns': columns});
```

Comment: so I would re-initialize the table? that seems dangerous

Comment: You're not really recreating the table just telling datatables to redraw with the updated settings using myTableInstance.fnDraw();

Comment: would I include all of the other settings it was originally init'd with? or just set the sortable stuff? its init'd with a whole lot of settings, event functions, etc

Comment: If you set aoColumns to a variable outside of the datatables object then all you have to do is modify that variable and call reDraw(). You don't need to reinstantiate datatables at all. In my answer I was only showing how you use the columns variable I created.